# Difference in "Initializing Each Device"

Tags: network-programming, linux-device-driver

everyone. I am learning LDD3. and has a question on below statement

"Note that struct net_device is always put together at runtime; it cannot be set up at compile time in the same manner as a file_operations or block_device_operations structure"

so what is root cause for this difference? the different behavior btw network driver and char driver?? Could anyone explain here? Thankss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of the difference is the *nature of the data* stored in these structures.

[file_operations](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/fs.h#L1664) is some kind of global set of callbacks for a particular device which have a well-defined purpose (such as `.open`, `.mmap`, etc.) and are available (known) at compile time.
It doesn't assume any volatile data fields which could change throughout the process of module usage. So, merely a set of callbacks known at compile time.

[net_device](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/netdevice.h#L1643), in turn, is a structure intended to keep data amenable to lots of runtime changes. Suffice it to say, such fields as [state](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/netdevice.h#L1664), [mtu](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/netdevice.h#L1729) and many others are self-explanatory. They are not known at compile time and need to be initialised/changed throughout runtime.
In other words, the structure obeys a strict interface of device probe/configuration/start order and the corresponding fields are initialised on the corresponding steps. Say, nobody knows the number of Rx or Tx queues at compile time. The driver calculates these values on initialisation based on some restrictions and demands from the OS. In example, the same network adapter may find it feasible to allocate 1 Rx queue and 1 Tx queue on 1-core CPU system whilst it will likely decide to setup 4 queues on a quad-core system. There is no point predicting this at compile time and initialising the struct to some values which will be changed anyway.

> the different behavior btw network driver and char driver??

So, to put it together, it is the difference between the *purposes* of the two kind of structures. Keeping a static information about callbacks in one case and maintaining a volatile device state (name, tunable properties, counters, etc.) in the other case. I hope you find it clear.